# iTunes Connect: No options when trying to add IAP

Tags: app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I'm helping a client set up their application profile on iTunes Connect and am running into a strange issue when trying to create in-app purchases.

When I go to the Features tab and select "In-App Purchases", then hit the "+" button, a dialog pops up asking "Select the In-App Purchase you want to create." There are no options to select, and there are only two buttons, "Cancel" and "Create", of which "Create" is greyed out.

The account is up to date with all agreements and IAP is enabled in the app's provisioning profile. There is no error message displayed. There is a notice "Your first In-App Purchase must be submitted with a new app version. Select it from the app's In-App Purchases section and click "Submit".

According to the official documentation, I should just be able to hit + and then select a type of IAP to create. Is the dialog bugged out or did Apple forget to document a step? This issue occurs under Firefox, Edge, and Safari, so I don't think it's related to my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this same problem. After contacting Apple Support it turned out the problem was I did not have the Paid Apps contract in effect on my account. To put the contract into effect:

1. Log onto iTunes Connect with an account with Admin or Legal roles.
2. On the dashboard select Agreements, Tax and Banking.
3. Click request button next to the Paid Applications Contract.